# Resource level errors in Google Could Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment

I wanna create a VPC using Deployment Manager in google cloud. After running the configuration file, I received the below error.

```
create-production-vpc has resource level errors
griffin-prod-wp: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/compute-v1:subnetworks","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-d836b08ea5ea/regions/us-east1-b/subnetworks","httpMethod":"POST"}}
griffin-prod-mgmt: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/compute-v1:subnetworks","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-d836b08ea5ea/regions/us-east1-b/subnetworks","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

The configuration files are here [gs://cloud-training/gsp321/dm](http://gs://cloud-training/gsp321/dm)

Comment: Hi, i have followed [the document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/community/network) and was able to create network and subnet

Comment: Thank you. I will check it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you might have used a zone rather than a region when creating the VCP subnetwork. In GCP, VPC subnets are regional resources.

error - `/regions/us-east1-b/subnetworks` - us-east1-b is a zone, the equivalent region should be us-east1 as in `/regions/us-east1/subnetworks`

Comment: Great catch !!!